# Proposition 1.3.8 in convex optimization theory book by Bertsekas

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

On page 32 of the book, [convex optimization theory](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Convex_Theory_Entire_Book.pdf) by Bertsekas, the author made the following proposition. I'm not sure how he gets $x \in ri(C_1 \cap C_2)$ by "using the lemma again".

[image]

And here is the [proposition 1.3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVPZR.png) used in the proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in \operatorname{ri} C_1 \cap \operatorname{ri} C_2$. You want to show that $x \in \operatorname{ri} ( C_1 \cap C_2)$.

Pick any $y \in C_1 \cap C_2$. Consider the line $l(t) = y + t (x-y)$. Since $x \in \operatorname{ri} C_k$ there is some $t_k>1$ such that
$[l(0),l(t_k)] \subset C_k$. (This is where the prolongation lemma is applied twice.)

Then with $t = \min(t_1,t_2)$ we see that $[l(0),l(t_k)] \subset C_1 \cap C_2$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $x \in \operatorname{ri} ( C_1 \cap C_2)$.